# Redirect to the desired page after authentication

Tags: php, laravel

When someone tries to visit a page which requires authentication is redirected to a login page. How do I redirect them to their desired page after successful login rather than default link?

Comment: `return redirect()->intended('dashboard');`                                                              I meant something like when a user visits a page and is not authenticated they get redirect to login page. So after login they should return to the page they wanted to visit earlier. The above worked for me

Answer (score 1):

See the default login controller file https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

There is a part with

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Change that property to your preferred endpoint and they will be redirected accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Open `app/Htpp/Controllers/Auth/LoginController` there is one parameter called `redirectTo` change it any route you want

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

or if you want to use some logic you can create a method called `redirectTo`

```
public function redirectTo(){
    ...
    return 'some route';
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is override the `redirectTo()` function on your `Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` like this:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return '/desired-page';
}
```